# How do I make the property of a JSON object required based upon the value of a second JSON object?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a JSON submission that I'm trying to validate based upon a number of rules defined in a template. This template defines a number of questions that are being asked to the user. For the submission, whether one of the question answers is required or not is conditional based upon the value of a previous question.

So basically

```
Do you have a dog? Yes/No
What kind of dog do you have?
```

The first question's valid answers are guarded using an enum, so that the user can only provide either `yes` or `no` strings as an answer to the question.

If the user answers yes to the question, I want the second question to be required, so that if the second answer is left blank when the first answer is `yes` then an error is raised. If the first answer is `no` the user is free to leave the second question blank.

Below is the JSON schema I have at the moment for this.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "question3-9": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "answer": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Yes", "No"
          ]
        }
      },
      "if": {
        "properties":{
          "answer": {"enum": ["Yes"]}
        }
      },
      "then": {"requried": "#/definitions/question3-257"}
    },
    "question3-257": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "answer": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "form_submission": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "sections": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "3": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "questions": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "9": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/question3-9"
                    },
                    "257": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/question3-257"
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "257"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "3"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I thought that by using the if-then-else available in JSON-Schema7 I'd be able to set the second question to required, but it doesn't seem to work like this.

Here is the submission that is being validated using the above schema.

```
{
  "form_submission": {
    "sections": {
      "3": {
        "questions": {
          "9": {
            "answer": "Yes",
          },
          "257": {
            "answer": "",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Updated JSON Schema:

```
"3": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "questions": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "9": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/question3-9"
                      },
                      "257": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/question3-257"
                      }
                    },
                    "if": {
                      "properties":{
                        "answer": {"const": "Home improvements (General)"}
                      }
                    },
                    "then": {"required": ["257"]}
                  }
                }
              }
```

To be validated:

```
  "3": {
    "questions": {
      "9": {
        "answer": "Home improvements (General)",
      },
      "257": {
        "answer": "", //<-- This is an empty string but should be required since the answer to the abvoe question is "Home improvements (general) as defined with "answer": {"const": "Home improvements (General)"}
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the `if`/`then` keywords, but the requirement in your `then` isn't quite right.

The `required` keyword needs to be an array of strings, each of which indicates a property name; in this case, the *property name* is "257".

Additionally, you need to place the `if`/`then` keywords under the `questions` property, not in the definition.  By having it in the definition, you're required that the `questions.9` property has a `257` property (`questions.9.257`), but you want the `questions.257` property to be required.

Try this instead:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "question3-9": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "answer": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["Yes", "No"]
        }
      }
    },
    "question3-257": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "answer": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "form_submission": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "sections": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "3": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "questions": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "9": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/question3-9"
                    },
                    "257": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/question3-257"
                    }
                  },
                  "if": {
                    "properties":{
                      "answer": {"const": "Yes"}
                    }
                  },
                  "then": {"required": ["257"]}
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "required": ["3"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, I'd suggest using the `const` keyword in the `if`.  I think it reads a bit more explicitly.

Comment: Hello! So I've taken your advice and tried applying it to my schema and data. I have updated the OP with my new versions. However when I validate this using the online validator it processes with no errors. Really I want 257 to be required since the answer of 9 is `Home Improvements (General)`, what have I done wrong exactly?